# Lie algebras with two multiplications

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

I was wondering if some concepts of Lie algebras with two multiplications exist in the litterature. By this I mean an object $(A,+, \times , \star)$ such that $(A,+,\times)$ and $(A,+,\star)$ are Lie algebras, and there exist some  equationnal affinities between the two products (probably something which looks like the Jacobi identity).

For example : $x\times(y \star z) =(x \times y) \star z + y \star ( x\ \times z)  $.

Does anybody has ever heard or read about something similar ?

Comment: What does motivate this question?

Comment: denoting the null lie bracket $(x\times y) = 0$ and denoting $x\star y$ any other lie bracket that you can define in this same lie algebra, they satisfy this relation. But well, a little bit uninteresting

Comment: The motivation is that there exists a categorical description for Lie algebras. So I want to apply the same characterisation to algebras with two multiplications and see what comes out. What I expect is some kind of Lie algebras where the brackets talk to each other.

Answer (score 1):

*Post-Lie algebras and post-Lie algebra structures* have two Lie algebra structures on a vector space $V$, say a Lie bracket $[x,y]$ and a Lie bracket $\{x,y\}$, together with a bilinear product $x\cdot y$ such that

\begin{align}
x\cdot y -y\cdot x & = [x,y]-\{x,y\} \label{post5}\\
[x,y]\cdot z & = x\cdot (y\cdot z) -y\cdot (x\cdot z) \label{post6}\\
x\cdot \{y,z\} & = \{x\cdot y,z\}+\{y,x\cdot z\} \label{post7}
\end{align}
for all $x,y,z \in V$. This is related to geometric structures on Lie groups, Rota-Bater operators, homology of partition posets, Koszul operads, isospectral flows, Lie-Butcher series and many other topics. For a reference see for example the articles [Post-Lie algebra structures on pairs of Lie algebras](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_51_postlie_2.pdf) and [Rota-Baxter operators and post-Lie algebra structures on semisimple Lie algebras](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_59_rota.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the references ! But here it is more likely to have three multiplications, and the third one makes speak the other two together.

Comment: We also obtain conditions without the third one $x\cdot y$, which you could consider then, e.g., $\{[x,y],z\}+\{[y,z],x\}+\{[z,x],y\}=0$ for all $x,y,z$. There are several ways to consider triples $(V,[,],\{,\})$.